# How to make image DOM element responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = screenshots[i].content;
    img.height = '1000';
    img.width = '1000';
    item.appendChild(img);
```

I want the height and width to be auto or % but it doesn't seem to be working with it.


I also tried

```
img.className = 'screenshot';

.screenshot {
   height = '100%';
   width = '100%';
}
```

With everything except setting the height and width to pixels on the DOM nothing works

Comment: It is not responsive to send a huge image to the browser and then use CSS or JS to resize it. It is responsive to have the browser decide what image size to request from the server depending on viewport size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that

```
img
{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it works refer codepen attached http://codepen.io/anilnamde/pen/aBmLdj

```
// HTML
<div id="xx">
</div>

// CSS
div{
  background:red;
  width:400px;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

// Javascript
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src ='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

document.getElementById('xx').appendChild(img);
```

If you change width of div in CSS image automatically adjusts.

Comment: Good answer but I accepted other because he got there first with the code I needed. Thanks

Comment: @Medelwr it helped that matters... up-vote will also work :)